# Angular 2 : Braintree how to import and use it

Tags: javascript, angular, braintree

I'm new to Angular 2. I've followed some tutorial and create an application and now i'm trying to import and use braintree in my project but it doesn't work.

So far I have done this :

```
npm install @types/braintree-web
npm install --save braintree-web
```

And I have tried this code :

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-paymenttest',
  templateUrl: '../html/paymenttest.html',

}) export class PaymenttestComponent implements OnInit {

  client = require('braintree-web/client');
  hostedFields = require('braintree-web/hosted-fields');

  ngOnInit() {
    this.client.create({
      authorization: 'CLIENT_AUTHORIZATION'},
      (err, clientInstance) => {
      this.hostedFields.create(/* ... */);
    });
  }

}
```

But i get there two errors :

```
ERROR in [...]/paymenttest.component.ts (9,12): Cannot find name 'require'.
ERROR in [...]paymenttest.component.ts (10,18): Cannot find name 'require'.
```

Maybe I've missed some steps ? Or I should import it differently ... I'm a little lost can someone help me?

Comment: are you using systemjs or webpack?

Comment: Not really sure of what i'm using ( I've followed the tutoriel from angular.io) I don't really know what is neither of these

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to your typings.d.ts

```
declare var require: any;
```

Comment: I get these error where adding it : ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined. Not sure if it really worked out ?

Comment: ok your problem with require is fixed, that's a nother problem, you can create a new question for that and i will try to help

Comment: Ok i've found why anyway. But why add this declaration into the typings.d.ts file ? And not on the top of my component ?

Comment: TypeScript compiler doesn't recognize require natively, it throws an error if you don't add it

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple `import` statements just like:

```ts
import { client } from 'braintree-web';
import { hostedFields } from 'braintree-web';
```

You can check that [example](https://github.com/Bluescreens/Angular4_DRF_Braintree_Example/blob/master/client/src/app/payment/payment.component.ts) on how to use braintree with angular2-4.